# How to pass Table Name as parameter to HQL Query

Tags: hibernate, hql

Hi i want to pass table name as parameter to HQL Query
I have used String Concatenation as:

```
String hql = "from " + table ;
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
return query.list();
```

this implementation works well but it throws SQL injection exception.
Is there a way I can pass table name avoiding the exception

Answer (score -1):

Using **hibernate Query Language** (HQL) you can perform any database operation without using query.
It means you don't need to use table Name to perform any operation. you can do it simply by using **POJO** or **Beans**  class name.

`hql=" FROM Your POJO Class";

Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
 return query.list();`

Comment: Hi I want to pass Class Names dynamically without using String Concatenation.